# php is not working correctly with <noscript> tag

Tags: javascript, php

The code inside `<noscript> </noscript>` will be executed when js is disabled.But in my code eventhough js is enabled php code is executed .

```
<?php $test=0;?>

  <noscript><?php $test=1; echo "Js is disabled ".$test; ?> </noscript>

<?php 
        if ($test == 1) {
        echo "</br>"."Value of test is".$test;
        } 
        else {
        echo "</br>"."Value of test is ".$test;
        }
?>
```

Note: `$test=1;`  is working when js is disabled/enabled . `echo "Js is enabled ".$test;` this statement is executing correctly (i.e) it works only when js is disabled.

Comment: PHP is server-side; JS & HTML codes are client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable assigning code inside`<noscript>` will be executed  because it is server side scripting but echo statement will be executed and rendered as html hence it will be displayed in the client side as a normal HTML. so, It wont be displayed in the Browser when the js is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

`<noscript>` is for *client-side* code. It is interpreted by the *browser*.

PHP is run by the *server* and the result is then sent to the browser. The server *does not* know if JavaScript is disabled by the client.

Comment: I know these things already . Please read the explanation given above clearly . This  statement also belongs to PHP but **echo "Js is enabled ".$test; ** this works only when js is disabled and not works when js is enable .can you explain it why this this executed correctly.

Comment: According to you server side scripting will be executed always even js is enabled/disabled, echo statement which is inside the <noscript> is also PHP but does not executed when js is  enabled .

Comment: @Rajesh: I think you wrongly assume that the assignment to $test takes place but the echo call doesn't. This assumption would be incorrect. As already established, the PHP code is excuted on the server, i.e. the `noscript` element has no influence whatsoever on the PHP script. If you look at the **generated HTML source** instead, you will see that the `noscript` tag contains the echoed PHP output. The browser just doesn't render it if JS us enabled. That's how the `noscript` element works.

Comment: The best type of downvote is when you don't get an accompanying reason.

Comment: I got the answer and closed this question,so dont waste your time by commenting here..

Comment: @rajesh: that's not a nice way to treat someone who tried to help you.